# Missing credentials returning from Auth0 provider

Tags: flutter, auth0, flutter-provider

I'm trying to access user credentials from Auth0 via Provider package in Flutter.

This is my provider class for Authentication:

```dart
import 'package:auth0_flutter/auth0_flutter.dart';
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:flutter_dotenv/flutter_dotenv.dart';

class Auth with ChangeNotifier {
  Credentials? _credentials;
  late Auth0 auth0;

  get credentials => _credentials;
  Auth() {
    init();
  }

  void init() {
    auth0 = Auth0(dotenv.get('AUTH0_DOMAIN'), dotenv.get('AUTH0_CLIENT_ID'));
  }

  void login() async {
    try {
      final credentials = await auth0
          .webAuthentication(scheme: dotenv.get('AUTH0_CUSTOM_SCHEME'))
          .login();
      if (kDebugMode) {
        print(credentials);
      }
      _credentials = credentials;
      notifyListeners();
    } catch (e) {
      if (kDebugMode) {
        print(e);
      }
    }
  }

  void logout() async {
    await auth0
        .webAuthentication(scheme: dotenv.get('AUTH0_CUSTOM_SCHEME'))
        .logout();
    _credentials = null;
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

This is how I call it:

```dart
        onTap: () {
          final auth = context.read<Auth>();
          if (auth.credentials != null) {
            auth.logout();
            return;
          }
          auth.login();
        },
```

and this is how it is defined in the main class:

```dart
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MultiProvider(
      providers: [
        ChangeNotifierProvider<Auth>(
          create: (_) => Auth(),
        ),
        ...
```

I do get the login page, and I could login successfully and return to my app. The monitoring section of Auth0 is saying successfull login also. The thing is after login the credentials parameter is not filled. What may be the problem here?